# Object Type Not Allowed Error Appeared Recently in Debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Out of nowhere, my whole site is throwing an error when going through the Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fretailevolved.com%2Ffacebook-like-button.html

The error is:

> Object at URL 'http://retailevolved.com/facebook-like-button.html' of
>   type '213689662010141:product' is invalid because it the specified
>   fb:app_id '120744357936587' is not the owner of specified og:type.

The error just started appearing within the last week. I'm confused as og:type "product" is not a custom og:type!

What has changed recently that is causing this?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I'm trying to figuring out how to solve it..

Comment: Facebook has acknowledged this bug and is working to fix it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285421101492706

Comment: Very bad...after 10 days this huge problem is not yet solved :( Do you know a workaround on it?

Comment: I don't know of a workaround other than changing og:type to something else. Trouble is that changing your type if you have more than 10 (or maybe 100) likes resets your like count.

Answer (score 0):

> The error just started appearing within the last week. I'm confused as
>   og:type "product" is not a custom og:type!
>
> What has changed recently that is causing this?

Yep, Facebook is now starting to implement the "Open Graph" protocol. And according to it, you have not specified the objects in your app accordingly.  Either remove the offending og: tag, or get the object added to your app's definition under the Open Graph tab (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your app id}/opengraph)